# Which is the greatest integer value of $a$, for which $A'$ is asymptotically faster than $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

The recurrence relation $T(n)=7T\left( \frac{n}{2}\right)+n^2$ describes the execution time of an algorithm $A$.

A "competitor" algorithm, let $A'$, has execution time $T'(n)=aT'\left( \frac{n}{4} \right)+n^2$.

Which is the greatest integer value of $a$, for which $A'$ is asymptotically faster than $A$?

$$T(n)=7T\left( \frac{n}{2}\right)+n^2$$
$$a=7 \geq 1, b=2>1, f(n)=n^2$$

$$n^{\log_b a}=n^{\log_27}<n^{\log_2 4}=n^2$$

We see that $f(n)=O(n^{\log_b a-\epsilon})$, for example for $\epsilon=0.8$.

So, $T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a})=\Theta(n^2)$

$$T'(n)=aT'\left( \frac{n}{4} \right)+n^2$$
$$b=4, f(n)=n^2$$
$$n^{\log_b a}=n^{\log_4 a}$$

- $f(n)=O(n^{\log_b a+ \epsilon})$, then $T'(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_4 a})$

We want to that $A'$ is asymptotically faster that $A$, so it must be $n^{\log_4 a}<n^2 \Rightarrow n^{\log_4 a}< n^{\log_4 4^2} \Rightarrow a<16$

- $f(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a})$, then $T'(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_4 a} \log_2 n)$

We want to that $A'$ is asymptotically faster that $A$, so it must be $n^{\log_4 a} \log_2 n<n^2$

How can we find the $a$s, for which this inequality stands?

- $f(n)=\Omega(n^{\log_b a+ \epsilon})$, then $T'(n)=\Theta(f(n))=\Theta(n^2)$
- So, in this case, we cannot find $a'$s so that $A'$ is asymptotically faster than $A$.

Is that's what I have tried right?

**EDIT**:

Could we also say it as follows?

We have the recurrence relation $T(n)=7T\left( \frac{n}{2}\right)+n^2$ and the solution is $T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_{4}{49}})$.
We also have the recurrence relation $T'(n)=\alpha T'\left( \frac{n}{4} \right)+n^2$.

$a=\alpha, b=4, f(n)=n^2$

$n^{\log_b a}=n^{\log_4 \alpha}$
For $\alpha>16$, $f(n)=O(n^{\log_b{\alpha}}- \epsilon), \epsilon>0$

So for $\alpha>16$: $T'(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_4{\alpha}})$

So that $A'$ is asymptotically faster than $A$, it has to hold $n^{\log_4{\alpha}}< n^{\log_4{49}} \Rightarrow \log_4{\alpha}<\log_4{49} \Rightarrow \alpha<49$

So the greatest value for $\alpha$ so that $A'$ is asymptotically faster than $A$ is $48$.

Comment: It looks like you asked a new question as an edit; it would be better to post that as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missteps in your application of the master theorem.

First

$$
T(n) = 7\left[ 7T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \frac{1}{4}n^2\right] + n^2 = 49 T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + \frac{11}{4}n^2,
$$

so let's call $a = 49$, $b = 4$, and $f(n) = \frac{11}{4}n^2$.  Clearly $f(n) \in O(n^2)$, so let's also call $c = 2$.  Then

$$
2 = c < \log_b a = \log_4 49 \approx 2.81,
$$

so we can apply case 1 of the master theorem (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)) to find that

$$
T(n) \in \Theta\left(n^{\log_4 49}\right).
$$

Further this form of the recurrence allows us to see immediately that $T(n) \geq T'(n)$ if $a \leq 49$, presuming the initial values are the same.  *(Why? This is important.)* $\tag{$\dagger$}$

Now let's look at the recurrence for $T'$, which is

$$
T'(n) = a T'\left(\frac{n}{4}\right) + n^2.
$$

We'll re-use the variable names from before, but in this case set $a = a$, $b = 4$, and $f(n) = n^2$.  Again $f(n) \in O(n^2)$, so $c = 2$.  If $a > 16$ then $2 = c < \log_4 a$, so case 1 of the master theorem again tells us that

$$
T'(n) \in \Theta\left(n^{\log_4 a}\right).
$$

Of course

$$
n^{\log_4 49} \in o\left(n^{\log_4 a}\right)
$$

if $a > 49$, so we conclude that $T(n) \in  o\Bigl(T'(n)\Bigr)$ if $a > 49$. $\tag{$\ddagger$}$

Combining $(\dagger)$ and $(\ddagger)$, we can conclude that $49$ is the least integer value of $a$ for which algorithm $A'$ is asymptotically faster than algorithm $A$.

Comment: Antonio How did you conclude the following?

Further this form of the recurrence allows us to see immediately that T(n)≥T′(n) if a≤49,

Comment: The first recurrence is $T(n) = 49T(n/4)+11n^2/4$, and the second is $T'(n) = aT(n/4)+n^2$.  If $a \leq 49$ then the recurrence for $T(n)$ is multiplying $T(n/4)$ by at least as much as the recurrence for $T'(n)$ is multiplying $T'(n/4)$, and since $11/4 > 1$, it's adding on more at each step too.

Comment: So will the inequality hold because both of the coefficients will be greater?

Comment: Also, if the initial values weren't the same, would the least value be equal to 50?

Comment: Yes, right.  If the initial values weren't the same then my guess is that for $a \leq 49$ the inequality $T(n) \geq T'(n)$ would be true for $n$ large enough (instead of for all $n$), but I'm not sure.

Comment: And something else.. Cound't the second case of the Master's theorem hold for $T'(n)$ ?

Comment: Only if $a = 16$, as far as I can tell.  Why do you think it applies?

Comment: In this case it will $T(n)=\Theta(n^2 \lg n)$ bit it holds that $n^2 \lg n=o(n^{\log_4(49)})$, right?

Comment: In order to apply case 2, you must have $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_4 a} (\log n)^k)$ for some constant $k \geq 0$.  What $k$ are you choosing?

Comment: In my notes, at the second case it is $f(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a})$ and from that we conclude that $T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a} \lg n)$.

Comment: And I ask you, is it true that $f(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_b a})$?

Comment: It is true for $a=16$.

Comment: Right, and $a = 16$ doesn't matter to us since we already know that $T(n) \geq T'(n)$ if $a \leq 49$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Comment: Glad to help.${}$

Comment: Antonio I am looking again at your answer. Could you re-explain it to me how you deduced the following? $$$$
Of course

$$
n^{\log_4 49} \in o\left(n^{\log_4 a}\right)
$$

if $a > 49$, so we conclude that $T(n) \in  o\Bigl(T'(n)\Bigr)$ if $a > 49$. $\tag{$\ddagger$}$

Comment: Sure evinda.  If $a > 49$ then $\log_4 49 - \log_4 a < 0$, so $$\frac{n^{\log_4 49}}{n^{\log_4 a}} = n^{\log_4 49 - \log_4 a} \to 0.$$  This means that $n^{\log_4 49} \in o(n^{\log_4 a})$.  Since $T'(n) \asymp n^{\log_4 a}$ and $T(n) \asymp n^{\log_4 49}$, we can then show that $\frac{T(n)}{T'(n)} \to 0$, so $T(n) \in o(T'(n))$.

Comment: Antonio But how did you think that you could choose $a>49$ ?

Comment: The idea of the proof is that if $a \leq 49$ then one thing happens, and if $a > 49$ then another thing happens.  Those are my only two options.

Comment: Antonio I see..Something else.. If we want to compare two recurrence relations of the form $T(n)=aT\left( \frac{n}{b} \right)+f(n)$, do the two relations have to have the same b?

Comment: No, having different $b$ wouldn't make them "impossible to compare" necessarily, it just might mean that you have to work harder to see how they compare.

Comment: Antonio I understand!!! Thank you!!! 
$$$$
By chance I found now this and at page 11 there is the same exercise: http://www.scribd.com/doc/55552407/Master-s-Theorem#scribd

$$$$
Why do they apply the first case of Master theorem because of the fact that the two recurrence relations have the same $f(n)$ ?

Comment: It seems like they're saying "it worked before, not much changed, so we should see if it works again."  Also there is a typo in that solution: the $48$ should be a $49$ in the sentence "There, $\log_4 a$ must be $\lg 7$, which happens when $a=48$."

Comment: Antonio But if $\log_4 a$ is $49$ and the solution of the recurrence relation $T'(n)$ is $\Theta(n^{\log_4 a})$, won't the two algorithms be the same fast?
$$$$
Also I think the way you did it, it is more understandable.. Do you agree?

Comment: They would be Big $\Theta$ of each other if $a = 49$, yes.  So in that sense $A'$ and $A$ would be the same speed.  Perhaps my answer should state this somewhere.

Comment: So for $a=49$, $A$ and $A'$ have the same speed and the greatest value of $a$ for which $A'$ is asymptotically faster is $48$, Antonio ?

Comment: If that's what you mean by asymptotically faster then yes.  If $a=49$ then $A'$ is still faster than $A$ since $T'(n) \leq T(n)$.

Comment: How could I formulate it, Antonio? :/

Comment: We should probably end this conversation, it has gotten quite long.  Farewell :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21734/discussion-between-evinda-and-antonio-vargas).